# Inline elements with ellipsis on text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this HTML where I'm trying to make the elements inline and let the title text have ellipsis, if the the page width can't fit the elements.

QUESTION:
How do I achieve the elements being inline and ellipsis on the title text?

The layout on a page that is wide enough looks like this: (where the 'i' is a clickable icon and the middle is text)

```
+---+----------------------+---+
| i | Title text           | i |
+---+----------------------+---+
```

If the page width responds and is too narrow to contain the elements, I want the title to have an ellipsis and the result should look like this:

```
+---+--------------+---+
| i | Title t...   | i |
+---+--------------+---+
```

so that the icons are still showing and nothing wraps to new lines.

Currently, it wraps and the text has ellipsis like this:

```
+---+
| i | 
+---+--------+
| Title t... |
+---+--------+
| i |
+---+
```

The code looks like this

```css
    .ellipsis{
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    .visible-xs {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="visible-xs">
            <i class="fa fa-indent"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="ellipsis">
            Title text
        </div>
        <a>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Note that the visible-xs class has `display: block`, and I need this class to remove the element, when the page is wide enough. It comes from responsive-visibility.less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option just add this to the `col-md-6` element:

```
.myclass {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  justify-content: flex-start; /* EDIT */
}
```

Cheers!

```css
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.visible-xs {
    display: block;
}

.myclass {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  justify-content: flex-start; /* EDIT */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-md-6 myclass">
  <a class="visible-xs">
    <i class="fa fa-indent"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    Title text
  </div>
  <a>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That kinda works, but one thing is missing, that I hadn't clarified enough. The right hand icon (pencil) has to be attached to the end of the text instead of floating right. Can you help adjusting to that? Thanks.

Comment: Well I guess you need to know or set the width of each element for that... `flexbox` distributes the space when you give `space-between`... maybe `justify-content: flex-start` is an option ?

Comment: Wow! That's brilliant. The `flex-start` works like a charm. I'm gonna go with this for now and try to figure out what browser support is missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Max-width or width should be mentioned for `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to work.

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/RHYtvupwLJZ7L4eCSib1?p=preview

```css
.ellipsis {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.ellipsis span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.visible-xs {
    display: block;
}

a, div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <a class="visible-xs">
        ji
    </a>
    <div class="ellipsis">
        <span>Title text</span>
    </div>
    <a>
        hi
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The ellipsis works fine. The problem is is that the other elements wrap instead of staying inline. The width of the element comes from the `class="col-md-6"`, so there is a width already. So obviously, I want the icon to the right of the text to take up a certain space which is then not available for the Title text.

Comment: I simply can't get that to work if I remove the max-width. There is no max-width, which is the whole point of the operation :-) I want it to show without any wrapping, but when the screen gets narrow, I want to remove the least important part of the UI, which in this case is the end of the title. Can you suggest something without the max-width? Thanks.

Comment: if you want ellipsis then you should mention a max-width. If width is a problem. I modified the answer above to add a `span` tag inside ellipsis. And you can give ellipsis class whatever width you want. and can add max-width to the span. Also check demo for reference